# How to "multiplicate" 2 lists in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
{
'ip': ['10.100.1.38', '10.100.1.39', '10.100.1.35'], 
 'port': ['3380', '3381', '3382', '3383', '3384', '3385', '3386', '3387']
}
```

I want to get list:

```
[
 "10.100.1.38::3380"... "10.100.1.38::3387",
 "10.100.1.39::3380"... "10.100.1.39::3387",
 "10.100.1.35::3380"... "10.100.1.38::3387" 
]
```

Comment: Great! Have fun implementing it! If you get stuck, ask a question here complete with what you have tried and researched.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try:

```
output = []
for ip in dict['ip']:
    for port in dict['port']:
        output.append(ip + "::" + port)
```

Comment: That's the clearest and most simple way to do it.  Someone will post an answer using `itertools.product()` shortly, but they are wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this neatly in one line using list comprehension:

```
out = [ip + "::" + port for ip in input["ip"] for port in input["port"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

res = [ip + "::" + port for ip, port in product(d['ip'], d['port'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = {
        'ip': ['10.100.1.38', '10.100.1.39', '10.100.1.35'],
        'port': ['3380', '3381', '3382', '3383', '3384', '3385', '3386', '3387'] }
import json
print json.dumps(input, indent=4)

output = []
for p in input['port']:
    # output.append( [i + '::' + p for i in input['ip']])
    output += [i + '::' + p for i in input['ip']]

print output
print json.dumps(output, indent=4)
```